# Code Academy python class "Good Morning Class!": For the record exercise

Tags: python

I'm stuck on this [exercise](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-qzsCL/0?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096#!/exercises/3).  Its asking me to print out from the list that has dictionaries in it but I don't even know how to.  I can't find how to do something like this on google...

Comment: What is it that you are supposed to do with the data? The link you gave just has a bunch of data and no instructions

Answer (score 1):

This is a more efficient answer that I found:

```
for persons in students:
    for grades in persons:
        print persons[grades]
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time you should specify more carefully what your question is. 
Below is the loop that the exercise is asking for.

```
for s in students:
    print s['name']
    print s['homework']
    print s['quizzes']
    print s['tests']
```